# If the value is 0 hide sheet otherwise make it visible

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following formula and cannot figure out why the sheets are not visible if there is a value.  What is wrong?

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
   If ws.Name Like "Summary 1" Or ws.Name = "Summary 2" Or _
ws.Name = "Summary 3" Or ws.Name = "Summary 4" Then

If Range("K28") = 0 Then
ws.Visible = False

Else

ws.Visible = True

End If

Else

    'do nothing
End If
Next ws
```

I tried the following as well but it's causing an error that it's missing a For:

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
       If ws.Name Like "Summary 1" Or ws.Name = "Summary 2" Or _
    ws.Name = "Summary 3" Or ws.Name = "Summary 4" Then

    If Range("K28") = 0 Then
    ws.Visible = False

    Else

    ws.Visible = True

    End If

    Next ws
```

Comment: You need to qualify `Range` with `ws.range` your second example is missing an `End If` that's why it is complaining about the `For`

Answer (score 0):

Your `Range("K28") = 0` is defaulting to the active sheet, not checking the `ws` from the `For loop`.

I added in a `With` so you don't need to write `ws` before each line.

If you are checking all your Summary sheets that can be shortened as well.

```
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With ws
            'If you're checking all Summary sheets you can do:
            'If .Name like "Summary*" then
            If .Name Like "Summary 1" Or .Name = "Summary 2" Or _
            .Name = "Summary 3" Or .Name = "Summary 4" Then
            
                If .Range("K28") = 0 Then
                    .Visible = False
                Else
                    .Visible = True
                End If
                'Alternatively: .Visible = .Range("K28") <> 0
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
```

As mentioned by Tim Williams you can shorten the code by removing the second `If` and replacing it with:

```
.Visible = .Range("K28") <> 0
```

Comment: or `.Visible = .Range("K28") <> 0`